# PhpDoc: @param и @method

Tags: php, phpdoc

Имеется класс. Большиство методов можно реализовать через вызов метода `__call()`. Поэтому можно описать методы через PhpDoc `@method`:

```php
/**
 * @method type11 m1(type1 $p)
 * @method type22 m2(type2 $p)
 * @method type33 m3(type3 $p)
 */
```

Но как тогда прописать (и вообще, возможно ли) описание параметров методов? Обычно, я использую `@param`.

Не хотелось бы создавать пустые функции только для того, чтобы иметь возможность описать параметры:

```php
/**
 * @param type1 $p Definition
 * @return type11
 */
public function m1(type1 $p){}

/**
 * @param type2 $p Definition
 * @return type22
 */
public function m2(type2 $p){}

/**
 * @param type3 $p Definition
 * @return type33
 */
public function m3(type3 $p){}
```

Можно ли только средствами PhpDoc описать и методы и их параметры?

**P.S.** Нет, в `__call` у меня нет "простыни" if или switch. Там просто curl вызов с заданными параметрами.

Comment: Не совсем понятно что вам нужно. Если вам нужна вариация типов параметров, либо возвращаемых данных, то в phpdoc это прописывается как type1|type2|type3 ([документация](https://docs.phpdoc.org/latest/guides/types.html#multiple-types-combined))

Comment: Нужно, чтобы я мог указывать не только тип аргументов, но и их описание.
`@method` позволяет указать название, описание и тип возвращаемого значения функции, список и типы аргументов. Но как задать описание аргументов?